# Problem with condition statement in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if (txt_SendAt.Text != null)
{
    //string SendAt_date = txt_Respondby.Text;
    DateTime Send_date = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_SendAt.Text);

    param[15] = new MySqlParameter("@SendDate", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
    param[15].Value = Send_date;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SendDate", Send_date);     

}
else
{
    param[15] = new MySqlParameter("@SendDate", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
    param[15].Value = now;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SendDate", now);

}
```

I have a text box where i select date and time from a calender. When I leave the text box empty it should execute the statements in else condition but it executes the statement in if. Where am I going wrong

I am getting this error if i leave it blank String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: is txt_SendAt a text box or the text in the text box?

Comment: My guess is that `now` is a DateTime variable (probably set to DateTime.Now). Is that correct or is it a string? If a string, what's it's value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're testing if the textbox itself is null, not it's text:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_SendAt.Text) == false)
```

Comment: This should be "!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_SendAt.Text)" if it used in the "if" condition in the OP's code.

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txt_SendAt.Text)` instead of checking for null.

You're checking if the control is `null`.  It won't be `null`; you need to check if the `Text` property of the text box has a value.  So if you use `IsNullOrEmpty` or `IsNullOrWhitespace`, you'll do a dual check -- if the control's property is null (unlikely) or if it's just blank space (or spaces).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_SendAt.Text))
```

Comment: You have to remove the condition then :)

Answer (score 1):

txt_SendAt refers to the textbox control.  You want txt_SendAt.Text

Answer (score 0):

You should try change the if to

```
if ((txt_SendAt.Text != null)||(txt_SendAt.Text.Trim() != ""))
```